# openstack deployment using kolla erroring out

Tags: openstack

I have followed below document to deploy openstack using kolla and I have built all the docker images successfully. I am following this guide for all-in-one installation.

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/kolla/quickstart.html

I have cloned stable/liberty branch.

But while issuing kolla-ansible deploy getting below error.

```
:# kolla-ansible deploy
Deploying Playbook : ansible-playbook -i /usr/local/share/kolla/ansible/inventory/all-in-one -e @/etc/kolla/globals.yml -e @/etc/kolla/passwords.yml /usr/local/share/kolla/ansible/site.yml
ERROR: merge_configs is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
Command failed ansible-playbook -i /usr/local/share/kolla/ansible/inventory/all-in-one -e @/etc/kolla/globals.yml -e @/etc/kolla/passwords.yml /usr/local/share/kolla/ansible/site.yml
```

I have searched a lot about this error but could not find anything, any idea about this error?

Comment: I got the same issue here after following the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have right version of ansible on your deployment node. It should expect version >1.9.4 but < 2.0